# Why does 'static int' give a different answer while recursively calculating the length of the linked list?

Tags: c, recursion

I am recursively calculating the length of a linked list using C.

The structure of the node is as follows:-

```
struct node {

      int num;
      struct node *ptr;
};
```

There are two pointers **struct node *head** (which points to the head of the list) and the other **struct node *temp** which is the pointer used to iterate through the entire list.

The code used to calculate the length is as follows

```
int length(struct node *temp)
{
     int len=0;
     if(temp->ptr!=0)
       {
         len+=length(temp->ptr);
        }
    return (len+1);
}
```

This works perfectly fine. 
However, if I use **static int len=0;** instead of int len=0; it gives random answers .

For eg:-
    If the list is 1->2->3->4->5 , the value is 16.

I was under the assumption that static should be used during recursive function call , as only under such condition only 1 copy of the variable is made. Otherwise , each function call makes a copy and erases the previous value.

Comment: The differences between `static`, `auto`, etc. are explained in every C book.

Comment: Why would you want to use `static` here anyway?

Comment: @Olaf I don't think its OP's problem with `static`, but his problem with the way recursive calling works.

Comment: @haris: Not so sure. The code looks fine with auto variables. So there is apparently a missconception what local `static`s actually are. But it might be both, therefore the strong recommendation to read a book or tutorial.

Comment: @Olaf . I have gone through some of the C books who discuss the static auto topics. But I lacked the practical visualization of the concept. It was more theoretical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When len is static, it's not every call to length increment the same variable.

Here's what happens

```
1->
   2->
      3->
         4->
            5
            add 1 to length (length = 1)
         add 2 to length (length = 3)
      add 3 to length (length = 6)
   add 4 to length (length = 10)
add 5 to length (length = 15)

return length + 1 (15 + 1)

16
```

When you use a local length (`int length`), at each recursive call, length is set to 0 in this instance of the function.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, when `len` is static, the values that are getting added to it are

`1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15`

each for every recursive call that you are making.

and in the end, you are incrementing it again, so its coming upto `16`

For the code to work, you only need to increment `len` when the condition `if(temp->ptr!=0)` is true, and then call `length` for the next node.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need Len?

```
return temp->ptr ? length(temp->ptr)+1 : 0;
```

Comment: Elegant, but too elegant and could stand for a bit of explanation. Remember, OP was struggling with static and probably hasn't even seen `?:`.

Comment: Have seen ?: . But I don't use it frequently. So, it is not the usual direction I would think of.